# What is meant by the term "baseline noise" in this context?

Tags: noise, oscilloscope, measurement, terminology

I came across [this](https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/reduce-oscilloscope-noise-measurements/) article about oscilloscopes. Under the figures and scope screenshots there is a term called "baseline noise".

[image]

I googled but it turned out this baseline noise is used at different disciplines for different things.

Does "baseline noise" regarding a scope mean that the noise floor measured when the probe inputs are shorted? Or?

(English is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret baseline noise to be the RMS noise around the baseline, under what conditions we do not know. Baseline usually implies that the signal is around a 'relative' average value. Because the RMS measurement does not care about mean values, and only the noise is being measured, it doesn't matter what the offset in the system being measured.

I assume that the inputs would be shorted, because that would give the best results for a noise floor measurment.

Comment: That sounds like this is the limiting factor for the effective resolution. Is that correct?

Comment: Definitely, It is the inherent noise from the analog electronics of the scope.